# Adding multiple functions to a ViewPager

Tags: android, android-layout, android-viewpager

I am fairly new to Android development and i am trying to create a sliding carousel with buttons that link off to other activities, this is what i have so far...

**Main.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //Remove title bar
        this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    //Sliding Carousel controls
    MyPagerAdapter adapter = new MyPagerAdapter();
    ViewPager myPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.myfivepanelpager);
    myPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    myPager.setCurrentItem(1);



}   

//Sliding Carousel controls
class MyPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
    public int getCount() {
        return 5;
    }
    public Object instantiateItem(View collection, int position) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) collection.getContext()
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        int resId = 0;
        switch (position) {
        case 0:
            resId = R.layout.carousel_1;
            break;
        case 1:
            resId = R.layout.carousel_2;
            break;
        case 2:
            resId = R.layout.carousel_3;
            Button myButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.paymybill);
            myButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
               public void onClick(View view) {
                   Intent intent = new Intent();
                   setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
                   finish();
               }

            });
            break;





        case 3:
            resId = R.layout.carousel_4;
            break;
        case 4:
            resId = R.layout.carousel_5;
            break;
        }

        View view = inflater.inflate(resId, null);
        ((ViewPager) collection).addView(view, 0);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(View arg0, int arg1, Object arg2) {
        ((ViewPager) arg0).removeView((View) arg2);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View arg0, Object arg1) {
        return arg0 == ((View) arg1);
    }

    @Override
    public Parcelable saveState() {
        return null;
    }
```

I am trying to get the button working on case 2 at the moment (but ultimately all case's will have 2 to 4 buttons).

When i load it onto my emulator with

```
                Button myButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.paymybill);
            myButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
               public void onClick(View view) {
                   Intent intent = new Intent();
                   setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
                   finish();
               }

            });
            break;
```

Commented out it works perfectly, but when i include it it crashes on load.

I think the problem is that i am not correctly pointing the button at the pager view and the app is crashing because main_activity doesn't have any of the buttons or layouts i am referencing.

I have spent the last 2 days digging through similar problems but i am not sure what i am doing wrong, as an example, [this case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10088647/create-a-viewpager-or-equivalent-with-functionality-in-android)

```
v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dashboard_media, null);
```

seams to be the same problem but it is using a different implimentation of the adapter and i am not sure what i can replace and what i can't (I have tried and nothing seams to work), as i say i am new to this and i am sure it is something simple i am missing!

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ideally, replacing the following line

```
Button myButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.paymybill);
```

with

```
Button myButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.paymybill);
```

would have solved the issue.

But in your case, `carousel_3.xml` already the button `paymybill`
So how about in the paymybill button you add the following

```
android:OnClick="payMyBill"
```

and add a function in your java to handle what you want to do

```
public void payMyBill(View view){
  Intent intent = new Intent();
  setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
  finish();
}
```

Comment: Superb, that worked perfertly, i updated the function to... `code` public void payMyBill(View view){
     Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), ccpaymybill.class);
  startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
     }`code` Which seams to have done the job.  I have also tested with a second button and function and (after 10mins of pulling my hair out, then realising i hadn't added the new activity to the manifest) works perfectly.  Thank you very much.

Comment: happy to help. if it did work for you, can you accept this as an answer ? thanks